# Gitlab Backup Error: pack-objects died of signal 9

Tags: git, backup, gitlab

I have a repository that has 2 branches with a size of 3.5GB.  Each branch is about 1.5GB (the .git is 700MB by itself).

This is the error:

> Backup failed
>
> [FAILED]
>
> failed: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
>   --git-dir=/mountdata/gitlab/git-data/repositories/my-Project/my-git.git bundle create
>   /mountdata/gitlab/backups/repositories/my-Project/my-git.bundle --all
>
> error: pack-objects died of signal 9
>
> error: pack-objects died

Since my server only has 4G of memory, my assumption is that the backup code runs out of memory every time I do back up.

Is there any better way to backup? maybe one branch at a time to prevent running out of memory?

Currently, the command in my `cron` job  is:

```
0 2 * * * /opt/gitlab/bin/gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create CRON=1         
15 04 * * 1-7  umask 0077; tar cfz /secret/gitlab/backups/$(date "+etc-gitlab-\%s.tgz") -C / etc/gitlab
```

Comment: Signal 9 is `SIGKILL`, which is used by the "OOM killer" (OOM = out of memory). More RAM would help the most; more *virtual* memory, i.e., swap space the computer can use to move things in and out of memory, pretending that the machine has more memory than it does, will also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your assumption is right. Possible solutions are

1. Run git repack before backup
2. Add more RAM
3. Use tar directly instead of git bundle
4. Update gitlab to the lastest version may also help (not sure)

   [See this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24989)

Comment: Another solution recommended in [gitlab#16568](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16568): "adding a disk backed swap file".

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to repack the repository and don't want to use more RAM, you can also try to add the following to your git configuration:

```
[pack]
        windowMemory = 32m
```

I don't know if the value of `32m` is a good value. But the backup is working again for me. I faced the Issue with Version 15.9.1. But pay attention on where you set this configuration. If you use `git config --global` it is just global for the user you are.

**EDIT:** The problem popped up again without changing anything. I restartet the server and the backup worked again. I assume that the limit of resources is the main problem here.